# Задача на динамическое программирование JAVA

Tags: java

> Есть поле из клеточек, в каждой клеточке записано целое (возможно, отрицательное) число.
>
> На вход подаются 2 целых числа, больших нуля и не превышающих 1100: n и m, - размеры поля.
>   После них в n строках задано по m чисел, - число в i-й строке и j-м столбце символизирует число, которое находится в клетке поля с индексами i и j.
>
> При нумерации индексов с 1, мы начинаем игру в клетке (1;1), то есть в верхнем левом углу поля. За один ход мы можем либо походить вниз (если есть куда), либо походить вправо (если есть куда). Игра заканчивается в том и только том случае, когда мы доходим до клетки (n; m), то есть до самой нижней правой клетки поля.
>
> В начале игры, когда мы еще не попали на поле, мы запоминаем число 0. Далее каждый раз, когда мы попадаем в новую клетку поля, мы к запомненному числу прибавляем то, которое находилось в этой клетке. То есть если в (1;1) стояло число 5, а в следующей клетке, в которую мы пошли (например, если мы пошли в (1;2), то в ней), стоит 10, то при попадании в (1;1) мы запомним уже число 5 (0+5=5), а при попадании в следующую клетку (при условии, что это всё та же (1;2)) - 15 (5+10=15).
>
> Программа должна вывести одно единственное число - максимальное число, которое может быть запомнено у нас в голове к концу игры.

Ко всему этому идёт пару тестов.

```
2 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
Ответ: 16

2 3
1 2 2
1 1 1
Ответ: 6

4 4
1 8 2 2
7 4 6 5
0 0 0 0
3 4 3 4
Ответ: 28

10 10
1 8 4 6 20 3 9 8 54 7
54 2 8 3 7 9 10 41 5 16
0 0 37 6 41 56 81 29 93 4
83 12 34 60 0 0 54 7 2 1
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
20 18 16 14 12 10 8 6 4 2
7 9 4 2 10 20 30 41 31 21
40 30 20 10 40 30 20 10 0 0
-10 -20 -30 -40 -50 -60 -70 -80 -90 -100
-100 -90 -80 -70 -60 -50 -40 -30 -20 -10
Ответ: 375
```

Код, с помощью которого пытался решить задачу, но получилось только на мелких матрицах:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m = scan.nextInt();
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int[][] matrix = new int[m][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
        int result = matrix[0][0];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                if (i + 1 != matrix.length && j + 1 != matrix[i].length) {
                    if (matrix[i][j + 1] < matrix[i + 1][j]) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                result += matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: вопросы про учебные задачи должны включать код ваших попыток ее решения и конкретную проблему, которую не получается решить в задаче, а не "вот вам задача, а то сам я не могу" - здесь не делют за других их задания за плюсики, так уж получилось.

Comment: эти тесты у вас код выводит?

Comment: @pavlofff, прошу прощения. Вот я пробовал сделать задачу так 
https://hastebin.com/zogedowuwa.cs 
В маленьких матрицах работает +- исправно, но в больших не тянет, ибо проверка только на ближайшие идёт. 
Думал реализовать через дополнительную матрицу, куда вносить максимально достижимый результат, но не понимаю, как реализовать на коде.

Comment: @TimurVi, эти тесты даны к задаче, в комплекте. 
Первые две цифры - размер матрицы, остальные - составляющие матрицы.

Comment: добавтьте код, связанный с проблемой прямо в вопрос (кнопка "править" под вопросом)

Comment: @pavlofff, вродеб сделал всё как надо. Появился вариант сделать дополнительную матрицу result[][], но пока нет представления о том, что можно делать с этим дальше.